# HTML button is not submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-submit

I have an issue in which my html form button is not submitting form or redirecting to the specified controller method named "record".

This is the form page with POST method and action named "/record"

[image]

Thats the highlighted post route path

[image]

And thats the controller method

[image]

Comment: Use text code blocks instead of photos

Comment: What happens when you click the submit button?

Comment: Any reason you’re not using rails form helpers? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: The `method` attribute is not allowed on inputs in HTML. You set the method via the form so you don't need it anyways. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element. Also on a side note adding a space between attributes and `=` in HTML isn't technically invalid but it looks really sloppy since generated HTML never has it.

Comment: actually when i hit the submit button it suppose to show me parameters as hashmap but it does not perform any action.